# How to use the entity query framework to model the following query

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, seam, hql

We have a query which needs to check if a certain integer field points is not null and if appointmentDate is before current date? How do I write the restrictions expression for the above scenario?

```
@Entity
public class User {

...
Integer points;
Date appointmentDate;
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using Hibernate

```
<framework:hibernate-entity-query name="requiredList" scope="conversation" ejbql="from User u where u.appointmentDate < current_date and u.points is not null"/>
```

If using JPA

```
<framework:entity-query name="requiredList" scope="conversation" ejbql="from User u where u.appointmentDate < current_date and u.points is not null"/>
```